# automatically run command when establishing ssh connection

Tags: shell, eshell

I often work on remote hosts and I mostly need to be root, but I can't login as root. It would be convenient, if sudo -s is being executed automatically when I establish a connection with shell/eshell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tramp's multi-hop feature. Open `C-x C-f /ssh:user@host|sudo:host:`. Then you can call `M-x shell` or `M-x eshell`, and you work as root on host.